# NextJS and Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, next.js

I am currently learning how to implement nginx reverse proxy with nextjs.

I have tested locally with the following code and it works fine. (below are the working code)

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host localhost:3456;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:3456/;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

The above code works since location / matches the path when the app (localhost:3456) redirects to /home/en on first load. However, the challenge comes when i attempt to use regular expression...

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location ~* ^/home {
            proxy_set_header        Host localhost:3456;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            rewrite                 ^/home/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass              http://localhost:3456;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

which doesn't work, i cant seem to figure out how to handle the redirection from the nextjs app.

I have read the docs from https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location but it seems that i still don't understand what is going on here..

Appreciate your professional help on this regard!